# Given a function how to find the last square derivative that is still square integrable.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Hi guys I apologize for the poor naming of the problem, I am not sure what name will be proper.

I am working on the following problem:
$f(x) = \frac{x^{1+a}}{1+a}$ we want to show that if $s$ is the highest derivative of $f(x)$ that is square integrable on $[0,1]$ i.e.

$$\int _0 ^1 \frac{d^sf}{dx^s}dx < \infty$$

then $s < a + \frac{3}{2}$.

My attempts so far is amongs the lines

Fix $a$ then if we let

$F(x) = \int _0 ^x \frac{d^sf}{dx^s}dx$

Where we want to show that for $s< a + \frac{3}{2}$ $F(1)$ is bounded and otherwise $F(1)$ is unbounded. Now consider we take the derivative

$$F'(x)= \frac{d^sf}{dx^s}$$

After this I am a bit confused because to me it seems that $s$ may be a fraction and I am not sure how to deal with such a case. Please advise how to proceed, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac{\partial ^s\frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1}}{\partial x^s}=\dfrac{a! }{(a-s)!}\,x^{a-s}$

To be integrable on $[0;\;1]$ the condition is that $a-s>-1\to s<a+1$

so that the integral's value is
$$\int_0^1 \frac{a! }{(a-s)!} \,x^{a-s}\, dx=\frac{a!}{(a-s+1) (a-s)!}$$

In your question you ask for $s$ such that

> the highest derivative of f(x) that is ***square*** integrable

have you forgotten to write something?

Did you mean the following?
$$\int_0^1 \left| \frac{a! x^{a-s+1}}{(a-s+1)!}\right| ^2 \, dx<+\infty$$
if this is the case, then the integral converges to $\dfrac{(a!)^2}{(2 a-2 s+3) ((a-s+1)!)^2}$

if $2a-2s+3>0\to s<a+\dfrac{3}{2}$